# How do I change sublime text default PHP comment format to blade laravel's comment format?

Tags: php, laravel, sublimetext, laravel-blade

The normal comment syntax in Sublime for PHP is

```
// comment goes here
```

or

```
/* comment goes here */
```

However, in blade templating, the format is

```
{{-- comment goes here --}}
```

The default shortcut key in sublime text is `CTRL + /` and `CTRL + SHIFT + /` respectively.

I was wondering how I would wire blade's commenting format to sublime's default shortcut commenting key.

Any help would be appreciated!

PS: I am using the [Laravel Blade Highlighter](https://github.com/Medalink/Laravel-Blade) package for sublime text 3 on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl + Shift + P and search for "laravel blade" and Set Sintax: Laravel Blade.

Answer (score 1):

First open the package control:install package

> Press ***Ctrl + Shift + P***  then search for ***package control:install package*** then press ***Enter***. wait for same time till one window appear.
>
> Then search for ***Laravel Blade Highlighter*** then press ***Enter***.

You are successfully installed Laravel Blade Highlighter

Answer (score 0):

That's only the half truth. Primarily the laravel blade templates are HTML based and HTML comments format is:

```
<!-- comment goes here -->
```

But blade also knows *hidden comments* which are striped off before sending the HTML to the client. These comments format is:

```
{{-- comment goes here --}}
```

So if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> in a blade template it uses standard HTML comments.

#### How to change standard comments in blade from HTML to blade comments

1. First of all open the `packages/` directory and create a new directory named `Laravel Blade Highlighter` there (You can get there by selecting `Preference` -> `Browse Packages...` from the Sublime menu).
2. Here create a new file named `Comments.tmPreferences` with the following content:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
     <key>name</key>
     <string>Comments</string>
     <key>scope</key>
     <string>text.html.laravel-blade, text.html.laravel-blade source.php.embedded.line, text.html.laravel-blade comment.block.laravel-blade</string>
     <key>settings</key>
     <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
           <dict>
              <key>name</key>
              <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
              <key>value</key>
              <string>{{-- </string>
           </dict>
           <dict>
              <key>name</key>
              <string>TM_COMMENT_END</string>
              <key>value</key>
              <string> --}}</string>
           </dict>      
           <dict>
              <key>name</key>
              <string>TM_COMMENT_START_2</string>
              <key>value</key>
              <string>&lt;!-- </string>
           </dict>
           <dict>
              <key>name</key>
              <string>TM_COMMENT_END_2</string>
              <key>value</key>
              <string> --&gt;</string>
           </dict>
        </array>
     </dict>
     <key>uuid</key>
     <string>157b8800-b2cb-11e4-ab27-0800200c9a66</string>
  </dict>
  </plist>
```

Now the default behavior for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> is toggling the comments in blade format.

> Note: I made a pull request to the *Laravel Blade Highlighter* project. So this may become standard behavior any time.

Comment: I cant make this work with Laravel 5 + sublime 3, on Linux Mint. Any update on this?

Comment: Same here, Sublime 3, Laravel 5.2 with Blade highlighter plugin, highlighting is working fine but unable to comment out with `ctrl + /`